# How to add 'titles' to pygmap points?

Tags: python, google-maps, pygmaps

```
mymap.addpoint(1.29425, 103.8991,"#FF0000",'test')
```

Is the bit of my code after I made the following change in the pygmaps,

```
def addpoint(self, lat, lng, color = '#FF0000', title = None):
    self.points.append((lat,lng,color[1:],title))
```

But I am still unable to see title of the point marked on this map :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to make one more change in pygmap.py

Change 
`f.write('\t\ttitle: "no implimentation",\n')`

to 
`f.write('\t\ttitle: "'+re.escape(str(title))+'",\n')`

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution if someone still needs help with it. You will also have to update the drawpoints function and then the drawpoint function accordingly. This is what my function definitions look like:

```
def drawpoints(self,f):
        for point in  self.points:
            self.drawpoint(f,point[0],point[1],point[2],point[3])
```

def drawpoint(self,f,lat,lon,color,title):